# Does pipewire support locking volume?

Tags: pipewire

I have a USB interface for audio which has its own volume control on the device with potentiometer. No matter what happens, for some reason I mess up the volume control in software. I think what's actually happening is goofy programs like Slack and Discord or whatever are changing it. Either that or I'm an idiot.

I want to fix my device in pipewire so the volume is **always** 100% and nothing can change it. Is it possible to impose this restraint on the pipewire stack?

Comment: "USB interface for audio which has its own volume control" : Do you mean that the USB device has its own analog amplifier ? Which gain is controlled via some onboard potentiometer ? can be controlled remotely via the device driver ?

Comment: Do you mean that the USB device has its own analog amplifier ? yes Which gain is controlled via some onboard potentiometer? yes.